# PHP: Using 2 arrays in a foreach but one array containing null values

Tags: php, sql, arrays, checkbox

Hi I am quite novice at PHP but i have been learning as i'm going and this is the first time i have come on Stackoverflow and actually asked a question so please go easy on me :P

I am creating a work request system but i am stuck on one particular bit, I think i am missing something quite simple so i hope you can help me.

The form i'm creating currently has a number of check boxes (Selection) and textboxes (Quantity) and the procurement items are listed from a database by this query

```
<?php 
$query="SELECT * FROM RequestProcurementItems ORDER BY ITEMID"; 
$result = odbc_exec($connection_id,$query);

$requestitems=""; 

while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) { 

    $itemid=odbc_result($result,"ITEMID"); 
    $itemtype=odbc_result($result,"ITEMTYPE");
    $itemdesc=odbc_result($result,"ITEMDESCRIPTION");   

    foreach($row as $cell)
    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td colspan='2'>". $itemid ." - ". $itemtype ." - ". $cell ."</td><td colspan='2'><input type='checkbox' name='additem[]' value='".$itemid."'><input type='text' name='addquantity[]'>";

    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
} 
?>
```

The checkboxes are added to the array "additem" and the textboxes are added to the array "addquantity"

When the form is submitted the checkboxes & quantitys are executed last so that they can get the MAX(ID) and be indexed to another table.

This is the code for entering the checkboxes and quantity fields.

```
    <?php 
$sqlgetmaxid = "SELECT MAX(RequestID) FROM RequestFormProcurement";
            $resultmaxid = odbc_exec($connection_id,$sqlgetmaxid);
            while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($resultmaxid) ) { 

            $qarray = array_filter($_POST['addquantity']);

            // Query to Add Items selected from list.                       
                if(!empty($_POST['additem'])){



foreach($_POST['additem'] as $itemid => $quantity) {
                                        //echo $_POST['additem'][$itemid].$_POST['addquantity'][$itemid];

                                        $sql = "INSERT INTO ProcurementDetail (RequestID, ITEMID, Quantity) VALUES (".implode(",",$row).", ".$_POST['additem'][$itemid].", ".$qarray[$itemid].")";
                                        print_r($sql);
                                        odbc_exec($connection_id,$sql);
                                        odbc_commit($connection_id) or die (comm_error);
                                        }       
                                }
                            }
?>
```

The issue is that it works... only checkboxes that are checked are being entered into the array, but the empty textfields for quantity are being entered into the "addquantity" array so i tried to clean it using

```
$qarray = array_filter($_POST['addquantity']);
```

But it still contains NULL fields. So once submitting the query i am losing a quantity from my query after a space (sorry if i'm terrible at explaining!!)

this is how the query is failing (notice the 10,11,12,14 i did not check option 13 so now the quantity for option 14 is missing, i kept id and quantity the same for testing purposes).

```
INSERT INTO ProcurementDetail (RequestID, ITEMID, Quantity) VALUES (1001, 10, 10)
INSERT INTO ProcurementDetail (RequestID, ITEMID, Quantity) VALUES (1001, 11, 11)
INSERT INTO ProcurementDetail (RequestID, ITEMID, Quantity) VALUES (1001, 12, 12)

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in I:\IT\Web_Request_Forms_Database\UwAmp\www\includes\HWS\NewHWSWRequestForm.php on line 282
INSERT INTO ProcurementDetail (RequestID, ITEMID, Quantity) VALUES (1001, 14, )
```

Many thanks for any help in advance.

**EDIT: What i changed**

I've changed the sql query

```
    $sqlgetmaxid = "SELECT MAX(RequestID) FROM RequestFormProcurement";
    $resultmaxid = odbc_exec($connection_id,$sqlgetmaxid);
    while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($resultmaxid) ) { 

    print_r($_POST['addquantity']);
    var_dump($_POST['addquantity']);

    // Query to Add Items selected from list.                       
        if(!empty($_POST['additem'])){

                            foreach($_POST['additem'] as $itemid => $quantity) {
                            //echo $_POST['additem'][$itemid].$_POST['addquantity'][$itemid];

                            $sql = "INSERT INTO ProcurementDetail (RequestID, ITEMID, Quantity) VALUES (".implode(",",$row).", ".$_POST['additem'][$itemid].", '".$_POST['addquantity'][$quantity]."')";
                            print_r($sql);
                            odbc_exec($connection_id,$sql);
                            odbc_commit($connection_id) or die (comm_error);
                            }       
                    }
```

When we specified the key we did not call the string for the quantity.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ProcurementDetail (RequestID, ITEMID, Quantity) VALUES (".implode(",",$row).", ".$_POST['additem'][$itemid].", '".**$_POST['addquantity'][$quantity].**"')";
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [10] => 100 [11] => 111 [12] => 0 [13] => 1333 [14] => 0 [15] => 0 [16] => 0 [17] => 177 [18] => 0 [19] => 0 [20] => 20 [21] => 0 [22] => 0 [23] => 0 [24] => 0 [25] => 0 [26] => 0 [27] => 0 )
array (size=18)
  10 => string '100' (length=3)
  11 => string '111' (length=3)
  12 => string '0' (length=1)
  13 => string '1333' (length=4)
  14 => string '0' (length=1)
  15 => string '0' (length=1)
  16 => string '0' (length=1)
  17 => string '177' (length=3)
  18 => string '0' (length=1)
  19 => string '0' (length=1)
  20 => string '20' (length=2)
  21 => string '0' (length=1)
  22 => string '0' (length=1)
  23 => string '0' (length=1)
  24 => string '0' (length=1)
  25 => string '0' (length=1)
  26 => string '0' (length=1)
  27 => string '0' (length=1)
INSERT INTO ProcurementDetail (RequestID, ITEMID, Quantity) VALUES (1001, 10, '100')INSERT INTO ProcurementDetail (RequestID, ITEMID, Quantity) VALUES (1001, 11, '111')INSERT INTO ProcurementDetail (RequestID, ITEMID, Quantity) VALUES (1001, 13, '1333')INSERT INTO ProcurementDetail (RequestID, ITEMID, Quantity) VALUES (1001, 17, '177')INSERT INTO ProcurementDetail (RequestID, ITEMID, Quantity) VALUES (1001, 20, '20')
```

Comment: It would help if you process and sanitize your input before trying to do DB transactions. You should use a library to talk to your DB. String concactentation and `$_POST` are not things that should be seen  together when building a SQL query. It makes you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You can read about those here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: I recommend taking a look at this website for some best practices for PHP development: http://www.phptherightway.com. There is a section called Abstraction under Databases that provides some examples of libraries that you can use that support common database servers. It might seem harder getting started with a ton of other working parts, like that guide recommends, but it will make you a better developer and future "you" will be much happier.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, thanks for the link i will definitely take a look, i am always up for improving the way i develop. But for my current solution i am not worried about SQL injection the site is restricted to our subnet and is only for tracking IT requests. But thank you for your response i will check the website out!

Comment: An easy fix would be to set the value to 0 in the text box HTML.

Comment: But would that not throw my array even further out of line from the "additem" array? as i need them to be 1-1 really.

Comment: Yeah, you would also need to change the name of the field. I posted an answer for you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying something like this?

Set default value of the quantity input field to `0` and set the array index to match your item's id:

```
<input type='text' name='addquantity[".$itemid."]' value='0'>
```

Then, access the quantity array using your item's id as the array key:

```
foreach($_POST['additem'] as $itemid => $quantity) {
    //echo $_POST['additem'][$itemid].$_POST['addquantity'][$itemid];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO ProcurementDetail (RequestID, ITEMID, Quantity) VALUES (".implode(",",$row).", ".$_POST['additem'][$itemid].", ".$_POST['addquantity'][$itemid].")";
    print_r($sql);
    odbc_exec($connection_id,$sql);
    odbc_commit($connection_id) or die (comm_error);
}
```

Comment: Mmm, just tried this, i don't know if im doing something wrong but now no quantities are being passed into the array. Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in I:\IT\Web_Request_Forms_Database\UwAmp\www\includes\HWS\NewHWSWRequestForm.php on line 283 INSERT INTO ProcurementDetail (RequestID, ITEMID, Quantity) VALUES (1001, 10, )

Comment: Please run and post the output of `vardump($_POST['addquantity']);`

Comment: I don't understand how at `$_POST['additem'][$itemid]` $itemid is set to `10` and then somehow, on the same line, at `$_POST['addquantity'][$itemid]` $itemid is set to `0`. Are you sure there isn't a typo?

Comment: array (size=18)
  10 => string '10' (length=2)
  11 => string '11' (length=2)
  12 => string '12' (length=2)
  13 => string '0' (length=1)
  14 => string '14' (length=2)
  15 => string '0' (length=1)
  16 => string '0' (length=1)
  17 => string '0' (length=1)
  18 => string '0' (length=1)
  19 => string '0' (length=1)
  20 => string '0' (length=1)
  21 => string '0' (length=1)
  22 => string '0' (length=1)
  23 => string '0' (length=1)
  24 => string '0' (length=1)
  25 => string '0' (length=1)
  26 => string '0' (length=1)
  27 => string '0' (length=1)

Comment: Based on this output, the array key is clearly set. I think the $itemid is somehow not what either of us are expecting it to be.

Comment: Also change the name of your input checkbox to `additem[".$itemid."]`

Comment: Thanks for the help Jonathan, i've updated my top post.

Comment: I am glad it's working now. Good luck with the rest of the project!

Answer (score 0):

One option will be of looping through the array 'addquantity' for checking empty values. Whenever empty value is encountered, assign zero to it.
In this way, while inserting the values in database, the value will not be empty.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the issue will still be that the 'additem' array and 'addquantity' array will be completely out of line from each other.

Comment: In such case, assign zero in the 'addquantity' array for the corresponding unchecked 'additem' array values. The values which you are not getting in the 'additem' array are those which are unchecked.

Comment: The issue here is that the `addquantity` array is keyed numerically based on the number of input fields submitted, but the `additem` array is keyed based on `itemid`.

Comment: Then name the html elements of additem array as 0_itemid, 1_itemid , 2_itemid etc. As you mentioned that addquantity array is keyed numerically, match the number before underscore in additem array with the numerically keyed addquantity array.

Comment: Why would you do that instead of just setting the array keys in the HTML form?